# Returned value from dexie qualifies as object, but then it isn't

Tags: vuejs2, dexie

I create an object store with dexie.js and populate it with an empty object like this:

```js
db.version(1).stores({
  status: 'id, settings' // only one entry, no need to auto-increment
})
// Add initial data
db.on("populate", () => {
    db.status.add({
        id: 0,
        settings: {}
    })
})
```

Later on, a Nuxt 2 will populate "settings" with data coming from a server. However, I need to check on each route, if the `settings` object contains values first, before initiating the call to a DB. Therefore I get the "status" objectstore and I check against `dbStatusSettings instanceof Object`. This evaluates to true, when done "on its own"; but in the context of an "if" conditional an error is returned:

```js
// default.vue
async checkIfSettingsExist() {
  const dbStatus = await db.status.get(0);
  const dbStatusSettings = await dbStatus.settings

  // this returns true
  console.log(dbStatusSettings instanceof Object)

  // however, here I get the error message (see below)
  if ((dbStatusSettings instanceof Object) && Object.keys(dbStatusSettings.keys).length > 0) {
    // Found data in indexddb's "status.settings", so save it to VueX
    this.$store.commit('status/updateSettings', dbStatusSettings)

    // Leave function
    return;
  }
}
```

This is the error message returned:

```
default.vue?ec86:190 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Line 86 refers to `async checkIfSettingsExist() {`.

I do not understand, why JS suddenly complains about converting an "undefined" to an object, when it just has proven itself to deal with an object just a moment before.

What do I misunderstand here? What's my mistake?

[image: image of error in browser console]

Answer (score 0):

Again it happens that after posting it only takes half an hour at the most and I find the error myself.

This: `Object.keys(dbStatusSettings.keys).length`
should of course be
this: `Object.keys(dbStatusSettings).length`

I am ashamed, but I leave this post up anyway for future reference.